# Keep Office ribbon submenus open when changing multiple properties

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

Is there a way to change multiple properties at once of an object (smartArt, text, etc) from the ribbon in any Office program? For example in Powerpoint I want to change shape outline color and width, but once I select a color then the drop-down menu changes and I have to click again the shape outline button.

Answer (score 1):

To change multiple properties of an object, "Right" click the object and "Format Object". This will bring up a format window where you can change many different properties like, fill, line color, line style, etc.

The available options depends on the object you are modifying. For example, the first image below is for a text box. The second is for a picture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I know it is possible to do this, but this takes up screen estate, so I was wondering specifically about the ribbon interface.

Comment: In that case, no; there's no way to change the behavior of the ribbon buttons. However, once you've chosen e.g. an outline color, notice that the "color chip" under the outline button matches the color you chose. If you want to apply that color to other shapes, select the shape or shapes, then click the outline button itself, not the downward pointing triangle.